# Has my flash drive failed? (no media)

Tags: usb-flash-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure

Flash drive model: Kingston DataTraveler SE9 64GB

I was restoring the back-up I had made on my flash drive after re-formatting and reinstalling Windows 8.1 Pro, and it started behaving weirdly. First, it unmounted itself, then it randomly said files were corrupt, then unmounted itself again. The first time it unmounted itself I thought, "Ooops, I loosened the plug!" then unplugged it and plugged it back in, but the second time plugging it back in did nothing. When I go into Device Manager and click "Disk Drives," it shows `GENERIC USB Mass Storage USB Device` as opposed to a Kingston drive:

[image: Device Manager]

I decided to check out Disk Management and it shows my drive... but with `NO MEDIA`:

[image: Disk Management]

(Highlighting mine)

I moved the flash drive over to my Linux box, and looked at lsblk, but no `sdb`!

```
chronos@localhost / $ lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0 14.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1          8:1    0  4.8G  0 part /mnt/stateful_partition
├─sda2          8:2    0   16M  0 part 
├─sda3          8:3    0    2G  0 part 
│ └─vroot     254:0    0  1.2G  1 dm   /
├─sda4          8:4    0   16M  0 part 
├─sda5          8:5    0    2G  0 part 
├─sda6          8:6    0   16M  0 part 
├─sda7          8:7    0    6G  0 part 
├─sda8          8:8    0   16M  0 part /usr/share/oem
├─sda9          8:9    0  512B  0 part 
├─sda10         8:10   0  512B  0 part 
├─sda11         8:11   0    8M  0 part 
└─sda12         8:12   0   16M  0 part 
loop0           7:0    0  1.4G  0 loop 
└─encstateful 254:1    0  1.4G  0 dm   /mnt/stateful_partition/encrypted
zram0         253:0    0  2.7G  0 disk [SWAP]
chronos@localhost / $
```

I then wanted to know if Linux even saw the drive as a USB device, and yes:

```
chronos@localhost / $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 1bcf:05ca Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1bcf:2c67 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0489:e056 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0c76:0005 JMTek, LLC. Transcend Flash disk
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
chronos@localhost / $
```

(the `JMTek, LLC. Transcend Flash disk` being it, when I remove the drive it disappears.)

What does `dmesg` say when it's attached?

```
[ 3085.285731] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 3085.298350] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0c76, idProduct=0005
[ 3085.298376] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3085.298396] usb 1-5: Product: USB Mass Storage
[ 3085.298411] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: GENERIC 
[ 3085.298609] usb 1-5: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 128 microframes, ep desc says 255 microframes
[ 3085.298634] usb 1-5: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 128 microframes, ep desc says 255 microframes
[ 3085.299966] scsi3 : usb-storage 1-5:1.0
[ 3087.018278] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     GENERIC  USB Mass Storage 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 3087.019846] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
chronos@localhost / $
```

Also, since I saw `[sdb]`, I checked to see if `/dev/sdb` existed:

```
chronos@localhost / $ ls /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb
chronos@localhost / $ ls /dev/sdb*
/dev/sdb
chronos@localhost / $
```

So, `/dev/sdb` exists.

**UPDATE**

I was asked to include the output of `dd if=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1 | xxd`, and this is it:

```
(precise)zeb@localhost:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1 | xxd
dd: opening `/dev/sdb': No medium found
(precise)zeb@localhost:~$
```

Comment: Try editing your post to include the output of `dd if=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1 | xxd` -- I get the feeling the partition table is unreadable, but if it's there, that'll tell us what it looks like.

Comment: Try running a filesystem check on the prendrive. Recently had a problem on a external hard drive. I would not mount on linux any more so I ran a filesystem check and repaired the errors it reported. Runs fine again. You can do this in windows or by using `dosfsck`

Comment: @paradoxon Windows Explorer doesn't show the drive, so I can't use System File Checker. For some reason my `crouton` in Chrome OS won't install `dosfsck` from `dosfstools`. @Michael Edited!

Comment: In windows disk management window - when you right click on your USB, does it show "Format" option. May be if you can afford formatting - then you could possibly get through this

Comment: You can try to create a new partition table with gparted